# Store the filenames of .kml files into the attribute table of a shapefile

Tags: attribute-table, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, table

I have to be joining .kml files in a single shapefile. The problem is that the kml files comes with a name that when I convert it into a shapefile it is not kept in the attribute table. thus, I lose a lot of time by filling the attribute table manually.

I would like that when I receive the files, 1234.kml
and 2345.kml, the shapefile's attribute table appears with "1234" and "2345".

Comment: Besides QGIS, is the use of python allowed?

Comment: Yes, sure. You have an idea? Thanks for answering

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean with "appears with 1234 and 2345"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default QGIS merge vector layer in the Vector -> Data Management Tools adds two fields to the output:
Layer and Path

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark it as the answer